# Beanstalk initial git deployment

Tags: git, deployment

I have a live site on a server that I want to make a copy of locally, turn into a git repo hosted on Beanstalk, and then deploy only the files that were updated. Is that how it works already or does it try to push the whole repo on the initial deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that how it works already or does it try to push the whole repo on the initial deployment?

From the [BeanStalk deployment page](http://beanstalkapp.com/features/deployments)

> Deployment is triggered
>
> Files are uploaded, SSH commands are executed and deployment hooks are triggered. We log everything for you.
>
> Using SSH deployments and deployment web hooks, you can run scripts and commands directly on remote servers for more complex workflows.

So it is pretty much up to you to decide how you copy what changes Beanstalk has detected.
And on initial deployment, Beanstalk will detect that the entire content is "new" and must be updated.

- If your process is then an [`rsynch` over ssh](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-copy-files-with-rsync-over-ssh) (for instance), `rsynch` could detect and copy only the necessary files.
- If your deployment is any other mean, you could overwrite your entire live site on initial
  deployment.

In both cases, once the initial step is done, any further push to your BeanStalk repo will trigger the deployment of the changes only (a few files), not of the entire repo.